# Changing pixel size of camera

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

how do you change the pixel size of a URDF camera?

I follow the tutorial in Gazebo but it doesn't say how to do this.

Thx so much friends.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8280/changing-pixel-size-of-camera/) by [Paulo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1111/paulo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'll need to use [SDF](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=sensor#sensor_camera).

If you have to use URDF, then you'll need to add a gazebo extension to URDF that specifies an `<image>` `<width>` and `<height>`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paulo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1111/paulo/) on 2015-03-19**:
I did that and I got a bigger image. But does that change the size of the pixels? I don't want to change the size of the image I want to change the size of the pixels. I want better resolution by having smaller pixels

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-03-19**:
Camera resolution is the number of pixels in the image, which is specified by  and . The "size" of pixels is a concept for print and display on a monitor. For example, a digital camera has a resolution but you can't set the "size" of the output pixels.

**Comment by [Paulo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1111/paulo/) on 2015-03-19**:
It worked thx. I was confused sorry.